# Method 'Author' of object 'Revision' failed

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to collect the names of all the authors making revisions or adding comments to a Word document.  I do something like this:

```
Public Function collectAuthors() As String

    Dim cmt As Word.Comment
    Dim r As String: r = vbCr
    Dim t As String
    Dim i As Long: i = 0
    Dim rev As Word.Revision

    For Each cmt In ActiveDocument.Comments
        t = cmt.Author
        If InStr(r, vbCr & t & vbCr) = 0 Then r = r & t & vbCr
    Next cmt

    For Each rev In ActiveDocument.Revisions
        t = rev.Author
        If InStr(r, vbCr & t & vbCr) = 0 Then r = r & t & vbCr
    Next rev

    ...
```

Recently `t = rev.Author` started to fail with

```
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
Method 'Author' of object 'Revision' failed
```

This perhaps has something to do with the size of the document.  I am using Word 2016, 64-bit version on Windows 7.

I also tried a loop where the member of the collection is indexed explicitly as in

```
t = ActiveDocument.Revisions(i).Author
```

and it stops after a few (maybe 10) iterations.

What is the cause of this error and can it be eliminated by a different coding approach?

Or should I forget about this and extract the author names from  `word\document.xml` and `word\comments.xml`?

Thanks.

Comment: I seem to recall people reporting difficulties in large documents with lots of Comments when looping the Comments collection. If memory serves me correctly, the best way to approach it was to break things down into smaller chunks, by looping specific Ranges. For example, if the document has multiple sections loop the comments in each Section.Range rather than ActiveDocument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I read the author names from the XML directly.  There are several obstacles which are not difficult:

- The relevant XML needs to be extracted from the .docx file.  I used
  7-Zip as it's free and easy to automate, plus will work well when it
  comes to write the XML back to the document.
- The resulting files are UTF-8.  UTF-8 is not supported directly by
  VBA.
- The author names need to be extracted from the XML.  It is simple
  enough to do this with a simple linear search through the XML.  I did
  not do any XML parsing or lexical analysis.

I had no control over the input documents, thus was in no position to break it up into more manageable parts.  However reading the XML directly sidestepped the errors completely.  Lastly, this is much better than attempting to process RTF.